# Intraweb : View a PDF file

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I use Intraweb 14 for Delphi in my application.

I did not find how to view a PDF file in a web browser.

How to view a PDF file (which is saved in the hard drive) in the web browser please?

Comment: `WebApplication.SendFile/SendStream` I guess. See [the documentation](http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/classes/TIWApplication.html).

Comment: thank you Peter.     `WebApplication.SendFile('L:\529-Article Text.pdf' , false, '' ,  '529-Article Text'  );`     I wrote that, but nothing happens.

Comment: You really need to provide some more context and code. Have you tried putting breakpoints in your code and debugging it?

Comment: @Peter : here is the error generated by the compiler: '_Replay Already set_'